# List all functions used by php call

Tags: php, function, trace

Is there a way to list all functions used by php call?

For example let's assume that I have a page called `example.com/page_to_test.php` and this page uses multiple functions within the page itself or from other classes.

What I want is a list of all functions used during the call (at runtime).

Comment: Use `xDebug` for that. It is an PHP Extention

Comment: btw your url should be `example.com/page_to_test.php` using `/` instead on `?`

Comment: Read more here https://devzone.zend.com/1135/tracing-php-applications-with-xdebug/

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a tick function to achieve this

```
declare(ticks = 1);
$calls = array();
function tracer() {
    global $calls;
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    if (count($bt) <= 1) return;
    $function = $bt[1];
    $call = $function['function'];
    if (isset($function['class'])) {
        $call = $function['class'] . '::' . $call;
    }
    $calls[$call] = true;
}
register_tick_function('tracer');
```

After execution of your script, `$calls` contains each called function in it's keys.

But just do this for debug purpose, as it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

What can help you is the PHP function

```
debug_backtrace()
```

Read more about it at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php